Getting ClassNotFound exception when running customChange in Liquibase
I am trying to make Liquibase to run a custom script with customChange, here is my setup:
changelog.xml
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-latest.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="test">
        <customChange class="com.example.RunCustomCommand">
        </customChange>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>

Dockerfile
FROM liquibase:latest

WORKDIR /node-app
USER root
COPY . .
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install default-jdk -y
RUN javac -cp /liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-core.jar RunCustomCommand.java
RUN jar cvf run-custom-command.jar RunCustomCommand.class
RUN cp /node-app/run-custom-command.jar /liquibase/lib/run-custom-command.jar

CMD [ "sh" ]

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    networks:
      - test-liqui
  lobo-liquibase:
    container_name: test-liquibase
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    command:
      - |
        ls
        liquibase update --classpath=./run-custom-command.jar --changelog-file=changelog.xml --username=postgres --password=postgres --url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
    networks:
      - test-liqui
networks:
  test-liqui:

RunCustomCommand.java
package com.example;

import liquibase.change.custom.*;
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.exception.CustomChangeException;
import liquibase.exception.SetupException;
import liquibase.exception.ValidationErrors;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;

public class RunCustomCommand implements CustomTaskChange {

    private ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor;

    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
        System.out.printf("Hello %s!", "World");
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationMessage() {
        return "Custom task executed successfully.";
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws SetupException {
        // Any setup logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) {
        this.resourceAccessor = resourceAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationErrors validate(Database database) {
        return new ValidationErrors();
    }
}

With that, I have compiled my RunCustomCommand.java to run-custom-command.jar and pass it to Liquibase command: --classpath=./run-custom-command.jar
However, when I run docker compose up, I still get
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  ClassNotFoundException
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Reason:  com.example.RunCustomCommand
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Source:  PostgreSQL 11.22
test-liquibase  | 
test-liquibase  | Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.example.RunCustomCommand

I also tried to copy my run-custom-command.jar to /liquibase/lib but it didn't help. I am not familiar with Java, what I am trying to do in the future is to run a Node.js script from that class.
Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

see "man java" for the "classpath" argument.

here is what I got
This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.
To restore this content, including manpages, you can run the 'unminimize'
command. You will still need to ensure the 'man-db' package is installed.

--classpath=./filename tells that bytecode(if java still compiles to bytecode) will be in a cwd. the question is, what is cwd at the time you run configuration script? will java machine invokation know about where to find your custom.jar?

I even changed it to a abs path but still not work (/node-app/run-custom-command.jar)

I tried to change the class path to ./run-custom-command123.jar and it throw some not found error so I guess ./run-custom-command.jar works

what errors do you have? at what stage? im confused. be specific.

When I run that docker container, it run this command:
liquibase update --classpath=./run-custom-command.jar --changelog-file=changelog.xml --username=postgres --password=postgres --url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
And i got this error:
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  ClassNotFoundException
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Reason:  com.example.RunCustomCommand
test-liquibase  | ERROR: Exception Primary Source:  PostgreSQL 11.22
test-liquibase  |
test-liquibase  | Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.example.RunCustomCommand

This question is similar to: exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/Scope. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As the file is inside /liquibase/lib , you don't need the --classpath parameter. Try removing it.
Why? you are copying the file inside liquibase/lib directory:
RUN cp /node-app/run-custom-command.jar /liquibase/lib/run-custom-command.jar

Liquibase automatically loads everything inside this directory to the classpath, you don't need to use classpath if the file is there. After that you are pointing to it again using --classpath (and I believe it should be --classpath=./lib/run-custom-command.jar ), so it may be causing some classloading issues as the file is being loaded twice ?
